# In Entity framework, we can use Model first, DB first, Code first but how can we create table programmatically

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ado.net, dynamically-generated

In **entity framework** we can use 3 approaches **model first , code first , database first** but each one of them needs manual hand touch(means creating database or create model or write the POCO class codes or entity class codes) before proceeding to the next step ( using EF in context ).

**What if I want to create database and tables and table relationships programatically and still want to have to features of EntityFramework 4.3.**

To be more specific , from this example http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307283 we can create database , tables and everything using SQL command but we can't have the advantages of entity framework. So if we want to have that what should we do?

**To give the ability to create dynamic table fields those steps will not be sufficient. In all 3 steps database , table  and table columns are fixed. There is no way that a user can create new tables or columns dynamically. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307283 in this post , it shows how to create manual db, tables and etc using SQL but it is based on ADO.NET but I want Entity Manager to do that. It will not be a magic, of course , there should be programming involed( I want to know the programming approaches ) .**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want ability to create the database and database objects using SQL commands. Then map these objects with EntityFramework context. Depending on your project you can have multiple context deriving from DBContext each doing some specific role.

If so there is Database class in DbContext which has function to execute the SQL. Simple call these functions on your context object.

```
MyContext db = new MyContext() 
//Where MyContext :DbContext (MyContext derives from DbContext)

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlcommand, params);
//There are other method in this class like SqlQuery Read documentation.
//The SqlQury is also available on the entities like db.MyEntitySet.SqlQuery(...)
```

If you want then your EF code to work with existing database then you can follow [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx)

If you want your context to use database name then you can pass it in constructor like below. You can try using such context with existing DB.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
        public MyContext():base("MyDatabase")
        {

        }
     .....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. By db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlcommand, params); code I can create dynamic tables understood but how can I map them dynamically in my class.

Comment: there's no dynamic/magic mapping, you have to create classes/models for each table. I think what you want is possible but not with EF/SQL server. I suggest you a NoSQL database, like MongoDB.

Comment: You mean map dynamically created tables with model classes which also are dynamic with respect to fields? I believe with EntityFramework the model which is mapped should be well defined. If you need dynamic model that represents database you should be using a framework like massive. [Check this](https://github.com/robconery/massive)

Comment: With EntityFramework max you can do is say if you have a Entity Products.   ------------------------- `List<Product> products = dbcontext.Products.SqlQuery("select * from products").ToList();`

Comment: In .net 4 there is datatype called dynamic remembered.. Maybe this can be useful here. @Abhijit , thanks for the link , it was really useful. Thats what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Code First approach of EF, the DatabaseInitializer default strategy is to "Create Database if not exists". So, based on connection string, DbContext will check if the DB exists. If not found, EF will run the necessary scripts to create the database, tables and relationships for you the first time. The scripts to run will be generated based on your model (POCO classes and mapping configurations/data annotations).

Imagine you want to create 2 tables: Customers and Orders.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get;set; }
    public string Name { get;set; }

    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    /* ... more fields*/
}

public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public MyContext(): base("MyConnectionString")
    {
    }


}
```

The tables, fields and foreign key constraints will be created when you instantiate the MyContext class:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    /**/
}
```

Comment: I know that but I don't want to write POCO classes. As I said it needs manual touches I meant those code first POCO classes, but I need to generate everything programmatically **so that I don't have to take those manual steps (means creating database or create model or write the code for database) .**

Comment: I don't get it... How do you want *programmatically* create everything without programming ?

Comment: LOL to John`s ans. Uuummm, by MAGIC?

Comment: No no of course , there would be programming for that. But I meant , to give the ability to users to create their own tables and columns based on their needs. If it is so then how can I do it. In all 3 steps database , table  and table columns are fixed there is no way that a user can create new tables or columns dynamically. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307283 in this post , it shows how to create manual db, tables and etc using SQL but it is based on ADO.NET but I want Entity Manager to do that.

Comment: Did you mean create tables and columns at runtime ?

Comment: Yes, I meant that and I was explicit about it by giving the link.

Answer (score 0):

I second Abhijit`s answer on this one. I am assuming that you already have your SQL line up ready (tables, SProcs, etc.).

Now to create to write the EF queries, you just need to access the dbcontext class in EF. As we do in LINQ too.

Here is a nice article in MSDN mag: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232765.aspx

Hope it helps!